# "which rails" works.. but "rails --version" doesn't.. how come?

Tags: shell, ruby, which, rails

This may be related to what i [did](https://superuser.com/questions/666715/which-command-doesnt-work-after-uninstalling-fink) here.. but when I type the command

```
which rails
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/rails
```

but when i type

```
rails --version
```

I get:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Development/android-sdk-macosx in PATH, mode 040777
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

how does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Command `which rails` runs program `which` that just searches for a executable file called `rails` on `PATH` variable entries (see `echo $PATH` or `env | grep PATH`). Executable `rails` is not run at all in this case.

Command `rails --version` executes the executable file `/usr/bin/rails` and it fails because of missing libraries.

Comment: hum.. so it seems the meaning of this is that I did install rails before, but then i deleted some of its libraries.. so now i got just a shell of it's former self (sorry for the dramatic wording).. and so i gotta reinstall eh

Comment: @abbood Yes, it seems to be the case. Install missing libraries or the whole thing at once.